# Finding duplicates in R between 2 columns

Tags: r, duplicates

column1 with list of all oscar winning films and column2 with random films which includes oscar won and not won films.

```
column1       column2       oscar won films of column2(expected result)          
 Moonlight     Avatar           1
Hacksawridge   Spectre          0
Lala land      John carter      0
```

I want to find the oscar winning films of my random movies column2. so basically i want to compare columns 1 and 2, find the duplicates,which will be the oscar won films and populate oscar won films of column2 with 0 for no oscar won and 1 for oscar won.I tried duplicated command and it only is giving me true or false.

Comment: Maybe you just need `with(dat, column2 %in% column1)` . If not, can you make your example a bit more clear, and add the expected result. [ ps by adding data to your question in a nice format makes it easier to geta nice answer : pls have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example ]

Comment: please see the edit

Comment: he meant give code that generates your toy data so we don't have to. but i think i wrote what you need in the answers

Comment: Can you explain the `oscar won` values. Do we assume that "Avatar" appears somewhere (but not shown) in `column1` but that the "Spectre" and "John carter" do not?

Comment: please see the edit.

Comment: okay, so does the code in my first comment work??? [ ps to convert `TRUE` and `FALSE` to integer use `as.integer` eg.  `x = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE) ; as.integer(x)` ]

Answer (score 0):

```
df$col3 <- ifelse(df$col1 %in% df$col2, 1, 0)
```

this will return a vector of length col1 and gives 1 if oscar in random
to return length col2 and gives 1 if random in oscar just reverse the cols in the ifelse